# How to create sticky navigation bar

Tags: navigation, sticky

How can i create sticky navigation bar just like this.

Comment: It's all script.  Why not look how they did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always to a menu with {position: fixed;}
example:

```
.nav-container {
    background: transparent;
    min-width: 280px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000; 
}
```

Here's some full code that you can play around with from CodePen: http://codepen.io/g13nn/pen/suFji

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/

Comment: Download:  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the bootstrap fixed [NavBar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). I think that site uses the same.